# SpringMVC Ldap Authentication @annotated

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to use the springMVC ldap authentication in my app. I am currently stuck after I get response from the server saying that the user authenticates successfully.

```
    11:56:16,289 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:90 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@7e18ddb9. A new one will be created.
11:56:16,290 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
11:56:16,290 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:129 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@32326
11:56:16,290 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
11:56:16,291 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
11:56:16,291 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:116 - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
11:56:16,292 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /login at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
11:56:16,292 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:116 - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
11:56:16,292 DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:205 - Request is to process authentication
11:56:16,297 DEBUG ProviderManager:152 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
11:56:16,297 DEBUG LdapAuthenticationProvider:51 - Processing authentication request for user: username
11:56:16,299 DEBUG BindAuthenticator:108 - Attempting to bind as cn=username,cn=users,dc=myorgnet,dc=global,dc=myorg,dc=com
11:56:16,300 DEBUG DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource:76 - Removing pooling flag for user cn=username,cn=users,dc=myorgnet,dc=global,dc=myorg,dc=com
11:56:16,350 DEBUG AbstractContextSource:259 - Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://myorgNET.GLOBAL.myorg.COM'
11:56:16,357 DEBUG BindAuthenticator:116 - Retrieving attributes...
11:56:16,463 DEBUG DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator:182 - Getting authorities for user cn=username,cn=users,dc=myorgnet,dc=global,dc=myorg,dc=com
11:56:16,464 DEBUG DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator:211 - Searching for roles for user 'username', DN = 'cn=username,cn=users,dc=myorgnet,dc=global,dc=myorg,dc=com', with filter (uniqueMember={0}) in search base ''
11:56:16,464 DEBUG SpringSecurityLdapTemplate:152 - Using filter: (uniqueMember=cn=username,cn=users,dc=myorgnet,dc=global,dc=myorg,dc=com)
11:56:16,468  INFO LdapTemplate:1262 - The returnObjFlag of supplied SearchControls is not set but a ContextMapper is used - setting flag to true
11:56:16,517 DEBUG AbstractContextSource:259 - Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://myorgNET.GLOBAL.myorg.COM'
11:56:16,542 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:300 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
11:56:16,542 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
11:56:16,542 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Mar 24, 2014 11:56:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Results] threw exception
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece ]; remaining name ''
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:319)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:259)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:606)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:524)
```

This is what I have in my Initializer:
    public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic springFilter = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
    springFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
```

My SecurityContext looks likes this:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) {        
    try{            
        ContextSourceBuilder ctx = authManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()
                                .userDnPatterns("cn={0},cn=users,DC=myorgnet,DC=global,DC=myorg,DC=com")            
                                .contextSource().url("ldap://myorgnet.GLOBAL.myorg.COM");           
    }catch(Exception e){

    }finally{

    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Active Directory for auth purpose. In your trace there's clear comment "In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection." indicating that you'll have to bind (with appropriate credentials) first. Can you confirm if you have LDAP server that support anonymous binding/search (Active Directory does not).

Comment: Hi, I am still getting used to springmvc in general. when i configured the spring security it came with a default login page where if i enter my credentials incorrectly I get "wrong username and password" without any exception. When i enter correct username and password it seems that the login does happen and i get a response from Ldap but then since i am not binding (which i am not sure - where i should define) the return to correct response the exception is thrown.

Comment: Just add `.managerDn("cn=bind_user,cn=users,DC=myorgnet,DC=global,DC=myorg,DC=com").managerPassword("bind_user_password")`to your contextSource and you should be all set to get working authentication. bind_user can be any regular user who can bind and search with AD server, doesn't need to have other special privileges.

Comment: That didnt work. I still get the same exception.

Comment: Can you provide full trace for org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception ... Looks like problem is in fetching the groups however only full trace will confirm that. I have AD authentication setup working at my end. Hopefully will be able to provide some inputs to you. Also confirm if you are using Active Directory indeed (groups schema depends on that).